# Sentry Cookie not attaching

Tags: laravel, cookies, sentry

I am working on Laravel 4 application and using Sentry for authentication. I need to add `Keep Me Logged In` functionality into my application. I have googled around and found that passing second variable to `Sentry::login($user, $remember)` sets up a cookie. I have done that and can verify that it is working from the browser (Chrome). But somehow whenever I try `Sentry::check()` after a day it returns null for cookies. Even when the cookie is present in the browser. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? Same happens when I attach my custom cookie to the response.

This scenario happens on my production server. Whereas it works fine on my local server.

PS: Lifetime of the cookie is set to forever (5 Years)

Comment: Comment if you need to see any config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working around for sometime on the issue I was finally able to resolve the issue by creating and attaching custom cookie to the response after login. And then wrote a `middleware` to check for that cookie. If present then login user and continue.